# How to put data in the blank field of the dialog box

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I created a tool that clicks an item on a webpage in IE, then the webpage dialog box pops up, I need to put data in the blank field of the dialog box using VBA.

I can't view the source code of the dialog box manually (right click). The webpage and URL are confidential, so I can't share that. I am using `FindWindow` function to find a webpage dialog box, and it returns the HWND value successfully. Here is my code:

```
Sub FindWebDialog()

    Dim hwnd As Long

    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Live Payments -- Webpage Dialog")
    If hwnd <> 0 Then
        'get the htmldocument
    Else
        MsgBox "no dialog found"
    End If

End Sub
```

I think that if I get the return value of the `FindWindow`, from there I can retrieve the source code of the webpage dialog box, then use it to find the exact location of the blank field. I would like to know how to get the source code of the webpage dialog box using the HWND.

Comment: What is the webpage dialog box? What is the application? How is it opened?

Comment: Also please run the code `For Each oWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows: Debug.Print oWnd.Hwnd; TypeName(oWnd.Document): Next` when the dialog box is opened, and check whether the HWND returned by `FindWindow` exists in output.

Comment: Note, if you know the title ("Live Payment -- Webpage Dialog") then you may just loop through each explorer window (as in my comment) and find the necessary IE window by matching title. Thus, `FindWindow` isn't necessary.

Comment: I already done that but it did not find the dialog box, but when I use findwindow it returns a value 461854, I assume findwindow found the dialog box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry not responding to you questions above, been searching other sites for help. 
Using the code above, did not find the dialog box, the IE dialog box is opened when a link was click inside the IE parent window and it is modal. The problem is only findwindow can find the dialog box and findwindow only returns HWND(windows handle which is a Long Integer). I found some code getting the htmldocument of the dialog box using HWND as the reference. (below)

```
Private Type UUID
   Data1 As Long
   Data2 As Integer
   Data3 As Integer
   Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" _
   Alias "GetClassNameA" ( _
   ByVal hWnd As Long, _
   ByVal lpClassName As String, _
   ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" ( _
   ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
   ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, _
   lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function RegisterWindowMessage Lib "user32" _
   Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" ( _
   ByVal lpString As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" _
   Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" ( _
   ByVal hWnd As Long, _
   ByVal msg As Long, _
   ByVal wParam As Long, _
   lParam As Any, _
   ByVal fuFlags As Long, _
   ByVal uTimeout As Long, _
   lpdwResult As Long) As Long

Private Const SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = &H2

Private Declare Function ObjectFromLresult Lib "oleacc" ( _
   ByVal lResult As Long, _
   riid As UUID, _
   ByVal wParam As Long, _
   ppvObject As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
   Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
   ByVal lpClassName As String, _
   ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Public Function IEDOMFromhWnd(ByVal hWnd As Long) As IHTMLDocument
Dim IID_IHTMLDocument As UUID
Dim hWndChild As Long
Dim lRes As Long
Dim lMsg As Long
Dim hr As Long

   If hWnd <> 0 Then

      If Not IsIEServerWindow(hWnd) Then

         ' Find a child IE server window
         EnumChildWindows hWnd, AddressOf EnumChildProc, hWnd

      End If

      If hWnd <> 0 Then

         ' Register the message
         lMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")

         ' Get the object pointer
         Call SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, lMsg, 0, 0, _
                 SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, lRes)

         If lRes Then

            ' Initialize the interface ID
            With IID_IHTMLDocument
               .Data1 = &H626FC520
               .Data2 = &HA41E
               .Data3 = &H11CF
               .Data4(0) = &HA7
               .Data4(1) = &H31
               .Data4(2) = &H0
               .Data4(3) = &HA0
               .Data4(4) = &HC9
               .Data4(5) = &H8
               .Data4(6) = &H26
               .Data4(7) = &H37
            End With

            ' Get the object from lRes
            hr = ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument, 0, IEDOMFromhWnd)

         End If

      End If

   End If

End Function

Public Function IsIEServerWindow(ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean
    Dim lRes As Long
    Dim sClassName As String

    'Initialize the buffer
    sClassName = String$(100, 0)

    'Get the window class name
    lRes = GetClassName(hWnd, sClassName, Len(sClassName))
    sClassName = Left$(sClassName, lRes)

    IsIEServerWindow = StrComp(sClassName, _
                    "Internet Explorer_Server", _
                    vbTextCompare) = 0
End Function
```

And use it this code to retrieve the htmldocument so I can search for the corresponding element of a text field that I need.

```
Sub HtmlDocFromHandle()
  Dim myHandle As Long, iHtml2 As IHTMLDocument2
  Dim ieobj As Object

  myHandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, "TITLE OF THE WINDOW")
  If myHandle <> 0 Then
    Set ihtml2 = IEDOMFromhWnd(hForm)
    Set ieobj = ihtml2.activeElement
    Debug.Print ieobj.document
  Else
    MsgBox "Window not found"
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what actually is that dialog box. Is it a part of the webpage document, or opened within new IE popup window? Is it modal?

Please make a screenshot of the dialog box, so that both the webpage and the dialog box titles will be visible. You may scrub the sensitive characters on the screenshot (e. g. in paint), and then upload it.

Also try to examine opened IE windows using the below code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim oWnd As Object

    For Each oWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        On Error Resume Next
        If TypeName(oWnd.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            Wait oWnd
            Debug.Print "URL   = " & oWnd.Document.Location
            Debug.Print "HWND  = " & oWnd.Hwnd
            Debug.Print "Title = " & oWnd.Document.Title
            Debug.Print "Error = " & Err.Number
            Debug.Print
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "Completed"

End Sub

Sub Wait(oIE As Object)

    Do While oIE.Busy Or oIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do While oIE.Document.readyState <> "complete"
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```

Do the following steps: make actions the dialog box to appear, find HWND using the code you posted in the question, then run the code shown above and share the output.

Both of them, the screenshot and the output listing + FindWindow's HWND, should make things clearer.